# Can I run a script in the background? (Apple script editor)

Tags: applescript, script

I have a script on apple script editor for a discord bot. (Discord is a chatting app my friends and I use) The discord bot is called "Dank Memer" and basically there are coins that you can get by typing in certain commands, such as "pls beg". I have a bot that I can run overnight to farm coins, the problem is that i need my laptop to be on that window to run it, since all it does is type the command and then press return. I was wondering if I could run the script in the background so I can farm coins 24/7.

Here's the code.

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat
        delay 40
        keystroke "pls beg"
        keystroke return
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

No, **System Events** can only send *keystrokes* to the frontmost *window* and is not capable of sending *keystrokes* to a *window*  that's in the background.